# Read in Column Names and Element Type into R Studio with a .SAS file?

Tags: r, sas

I have R Studio and data that came in a .CSV file. There is variable information including data element label, type, number of digits, etc. that has been provided in a .SAS as well as a .do file. I understand these correspond to either SAS or STATA. These are all (.csv, .sas, .do) in a single folder on my desktop.

While it is straightforward to import the .csv file on its own:

```
library(readr)
NRD_2017_Hospital <- read_csv("My Documents/Data/2017/2017_School.CSV")
View(2017_School)

SASIN <- "C:/Users/Quix/Documents/My Documents/Data/2017/2017_School.SAS"
```

Getting the headers and other variable information in isn't working. I've tried the library(SAScii) and it comes up with errors:
`data1<- read.SAScii(2017_School, SASIN)`

The error:

```
Error in if (as.numeric(x[j, "start"]) > as.numeric(x[j - 1, "end"]) +  : 
missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In parse.SAScii(sas_ri, beginline, lrecl) : NAs introduced by coercion
2: In parse.SAScii(sas_ri, beginline, lrecl) : NAs introduced by coercion
3: In parse.SAScii(sas_ri, beginline, lrecl) : NAs introduced by coercion
4: In parse.SAScii(sas_ri, beginline, lrecl) : NAs introduced by coercion
5: In parse.SAScii(sas_ri, beginline, lrecl) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

Is there a fix? How to get the data and headers to load together in R?

Comment: Are you asking how to parse the SAS or STATA code and tease out the names of the variables from the code?  How many variables are we talking about? Why not just copy and paste the text from those program files into a format that works for you to read with R?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without access to your file, it's hard for us to replicate, but `haven::read_sas()` has worked for most SAS files I've had to use:

```
library(haven)
data1 <- read_sas("C:/Users/Quix/Documents/My Documents/Data/2017/2017_School.SAS")
```

If this doesn't work, can you share a sample file somewhere?